# How to count number of published nodes of a specific content type in twig template?

Tags: theming

I'm looking for a way to achieve this in my Twig file; if the number of published entities of a content type 'promotions' is at least one, a certain entity should be displayed in a content type Shop. I'm trying to show a banner only if there is at least one published promotion entity.

I could use some help with the if-function. I've written it down with I'm trying to do.

```
if(published promotion entities > 0){
{{ drupal_entity('node', 2668) }}
}
```

Any ideas to get me going? Thanks!

Comment: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/if.html

Comment: You could filter the nodes in a View and then check the results with Twig Tweak, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet#s-drupal-view-result

Comment: Hi Kevin, I know how to use an if-function, but I don't know how to get the total count from entities from another content type. And check if at least one is published?

Comment: @4k4 That's a great idea. Using the result in an if function breaks the page partially, weirdly.

Answer (score 2):

In a preprocess hook function for your template, you can code something like this.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_TEMPLATE_HOOK(&$variables) {
    $query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
    $query->condition('type', 'promotions');
    $query->condition('status', 1);
    $query->range(0, 1); // only need one
    $results = $query->execute();
    $variables['has_published_promotions'] = (bool)count($results);
}
```

`has_published_promotions` will be available in your Twig template and will be `TRUE` only when there are published nodes of that type.

Comment: Hi. alfred, this results in an error: 

`ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in Drupal\Core\Extension\Extension->load() (line 4 of themes/custom/mytheme/mytheme.theme).`

Comment: Hi, I've amended the code to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view with a filter of published nodes of that content type. With the snippet below you can add `{{ published_count }}` to your page.html.twig

```
use \Drupal\views\Views;

function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // make the result count available as a variable in page.html.twig
  $view = Views::getView('published_promotions');
  $view->setDisplay('default');
  $view->execute();
  $variables['published_count'] = count($view->result);
}
```

Now you can do the following in Twig:

```
{% if published_count > 0 %} // print banner here {% endif %}
```

More: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/get-views-row-count-twig-drupal-8